# Selenium IDE - Click on close button in iframe obviously works but raises exception : frame no longer exists

Tags: selenium-ide

In my scenario, I click on a button on a website which opens a popin.
In that popin, i click some buttons (all is working fine) until I need to confirm by clicking another button.
Problem comes here. When I look at the execution, Selenium IDE obviously finds the button and click it because I can see the popin close and the result of the actions done in the popin on the website.
But the test fails on this button click with reason : frame no longer exists

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

They is a try/catch mechnism under development which could be used to mitigate this. In the meantime I exported my tests to run in webdriver and this issue no longer manifests itself.